Help Solving Second-Order ODE
I'm intrigued by the differential equation $$ y'' + ae^{-bx} y' + y = 0 $$
where a and b are constants. However, I'm unsure how to approach solving it.
I attempted to use SymPy and obtained what seems to be a promising approximation.
Here's the solution it provided (using a Taylor expansion of x -> exp(x)
$
\displaystyle y{\left(x \right)} = C_{2} \left(- \frac{a^{2} x^{4} e^{- 2 b x}}{24} + \frac{a x^{3} e^{- b x}}{6} + \frac{x^{4}}{24} - \frac{x^{2}}{2} + 1\right) + C_{1} x \left(- \frac{a^{3} x^{3} e^{- 3 b x}}{24} + \frac{a^{2} x^{2} e^{- 2 b x}}{6} + \frac{a x^{3} e^{- b x}}{12} - \frac{a x e^{- b x}}{2} - \frac{x^{2}}{6} + 1\right) + O\left(x^{6}\right)$
See the approximation and the one returned by an ode solver

Mathematica gives a solution in terms of a hypergeometric function

Maple gives a solution in terms of modified Bessel functions:
$$y \! \left(x \right) = 
{\mathrm e}^{\frac{-b^{2} x +a \,{\mathrm e}^{-b x}}{2 b}} \left(-K_{\frac{-b +2 \,\mathrm{i}}{2 b}}\! \left(-\frac{a \,{\mathrm e}^{-b x}}{2 b}\right) c_{2} +K_{\frac{b +2 \,\mathrm{i}}{2 b}}\! \left(-\frac{a \,{\mathrm e}^{-b x}}{2 b}\right) c_{2} +I_{\frac{-b +2 \,\mathrm{i}}{2 b}}\! \left(-\frac{a \,{\mathrm e}^{-b x}}{2 b}\right) c_{1} +I_{\frac{b +2 \,\mathrm{i}}{2 b}}\! \left(-\frac{a \,{\mathrm e}^{-b x}}{2 b}\right) c_{1} \right)
$$
